# Is there a word for 'to do until it no longer fazes you'?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm looking for a word that means '*to do or see, etc. something until it no longer fazes you*'.

For example, a doctor who is used to seeing blood will not flinch or faint at the sight of it. Usually that 'something' is unpleasant.  *Acclimatize* doesn't quite hit the mark. If memory serves right, the word perhaps begins with an 'i'. Of course, I could be wrong.

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence?

Comment: I would suggest *'become accustomed to…'*

Answer (score 1):

**Inure** — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inure)

> *verb, with object* (usually be inured to) Accustom (someone) to something, especially something unpleasant.
>
> *"these children have been inured to violence."*
> *"After seven years in the firing line with Rangers and three-and-a-half years prising out body pellets at Goodison Park, Smith is inured to criticism."*

See more definitions and examples from [OneLook Dictionary Search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=inure&ls=a)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you oh my gosh this has been driving me crazy until now.

Answer (score 1):

In psychology, there is a technical term, which the layman can also use:

**desensitize**

"desensitization: a behavior modification technique, used especially in treating phobias, in which panic or other undesirable emotional response to a given stimulus is reduced or extinguished, especially by repeated exposure to that stimulus."  -- dictionary.com

Note, the therapeutic technique of choice to accomplish this is called *Exposure and Response Prevention* (ERP).

Usage examples:

> As a medical student, you have to desensitize yourself to the sight of blood.
>
> With repeated exposures, you can become less sensitive to the sight of blood.